# How many stepper motors can you run on one Arduino Uno? Ideas on how to run 9?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, stepper-motor

I am in middle school and new to Arduino. I just learned to set up and code a stepper motor on my Arduino Uno from watching YouTube videos.  I want to set up 9 stepper motors to all run at the same time and at the same rotation speed for a science project I am working on. Right now I have the Arduino Uno with a 830 breadboard, ULN2003 stepper motor driver and 28BYJ-48 stepper motor.  I think I will need to use something different because I can see that my driver doesn't have more than one set of plugs for the wires. I got a budget for my science project so I am allowed to buy some new equipment. But I am confused about what I need to run 9. If anyone can help to suggest the best and simplest way to do this, I would be very happy. I feel like once I have the equipment, I can try to figure out how to put it together and figure out the code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each step motor need 4 phase driving pins, so you will need 4x9 GPIO pins, and you already tag 'arudino-mega', so I think you know what you want already. If you are looking for driver other than ULN2003, you can research on [this page](https://www.pololu.com/category/120/stepper-motor-drivers), please note that this is not product recommendation, but to give the idea of the variaties available, before you make any decision on your hardware, check the availability of library for a specific driver IC.

Comment: `9 stepper motors to all run at the same time and at the same rotation speed` ... connect them in parallel ... control them same as one motor

Answer (score -1):

You can use 4 N-Channel MOSFETs, get the logic level avalanche rated ones. Get something in the 5A or higher current range (lower RDSon). Your motors draw 240mA each. The higher the amperage rating the of the MOSFET the cooler the MOSFET will run. I am a firm believer silicon in place of heatsinks. In small it is not that expensive and you do not have the hassle of a heatsink.

You can then drive the MOSFETs from four port pins through a 50 Ohm resistor to each of the gates. Then put a 10K pull down resistor on the port pin, not the gate. Putting the pull down on the gate creates a voltage divider for the gate voltage. This is to guarantee the MOSFETs are all off when the system is first turned on and during initialization until your code takes over. I use the low gate resistors one to control oscillation and two to drive it hard so it switches faster keeping it out of the linear range where it will get hot. Be sure the Source of each output is connected to the ground of the motor power supply and that the arduino ground is also connected to this ground.

You then connect all of the motors in parallel and connect them to the drains of the MOSFET. I am assuming 4 leds (Pink, Yellow, Orange and Blue) from the motor to the MOSFETs drain and a common (Red) for +5 power.

This will give you about 1.4V more per phase when operating not dropping across the driver thereby increasing the efficiency. Also the wiring is much simpler.

Comment: Since the OP already has drivers for each motor, why not using each motor with its own driver and just connecting the 4 signal lines together?

Comment: A 50 Ω / 10 kΩ voltage divider will divide its input voltage by 1.005.